# Mysql Best way to query notifications like on stackoverflow

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

```
comments
+----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| id | content   | user_id | article_id |
+----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| 1  | Comment 1 | 2       | 5          |
| 2  | Comment 2 | 5       | 3          |
| 3  | Comment 3 | 1       | 6          |
| 4  | Comment 4 | 6       | 8          |
| 5  | Comment 5 | 1       | 6          |
| ...| ...       | ...     | ...        |
+----------------+---------+------------+

votes
+----+----------+--------------+---+
| id | type | user_id | article_id |
+----+----------+--------------+---+
| 1  | 1    | 2       | 5          |
| 2  | 1    | 3       | 3          |
| 3  | 0    | 1       | 6          |
| 4  | 1    | 7       | 4          |
| 5  | 0    | 9       | 4          |
| 6  | 0    | 1       | 6          |
| ...| ...  | ...     | ...        |
+------------+----------+----------+

notifications (object_id is the id of the vote|comment)
+----+----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| id | object_url| object_id |activitytype_id|  sender_id  | recipient_id | 
+----+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1  | /../../.. | 1         | 2             |       2     |       6      | 
| 2  | /../../.. | 2         | 2             |       3     |       2      | 
| 3  | /../../.. | 1         | 1             |       2     |       7      | 
| 3  | /../../.. | 2         | 1             |       5     |       2      | 
| 3  | /../../.. | 3         | 1             |       1     |       3      | 
| 3  | /../../.. | 3         | 3             |       1     |       2      | 
| 3  | /../../.. | 4         | 2             |       7     |       8      |
| 3  | /../../.. | 5         | 3             |       9     |       1      |
| 3  | /../../.. | 6         | 3             |       1     |       5      | 
| ...| ...       | ...       | ...           |             |              | 
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--------------+

activitytypes
+----+------------+
| id |    label   |
+----+------------+
| 1  | comment    |
| 2  | vote up    |
| 3  | vote down  |
| ...| ...        |
+-----------------+
```

I would like to get notifications like on stackoverflow.

I want to query the last notification (with comment content if the activity type is a comment or null if not) for every activitytype and object_url combinaison for a specific user.

For example I have 3 artiles A,B and C which all have 3 comments, 4 voteup and 2 votedown. How to get the last comment, voteup and votedown for every article ?

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT n.id, n.object_url , n.object_id, n.activitytype_id, IF(n.activitytypeId = 1, 
(SELECT content FROM comments WHERE id=n.object_id), null) AS activitycontent     
FROM notifications n WHERE n.recipient_id =1
GROUP BY n.activitytype_id,n.object_url 
ORDER BY n.id DESC
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help ?

**EDIT:**
This following query in farhadamjady's answer gives me the first comment:

```
SELECT
n.id,
n.object_url,
n.object_id,
n.activitytype_id,
cm.content AS activitycontent
FROM
  notifications n
LEFT OUTER JOIN `COMMENT` AS cm ON cm.id = n.object_id and n.activitytypeId  = 1
WHERE
  n.recipient_id = 1
GROUP BY
  n.activitytype_id,
  n.object_url
HAVING MAX(cm.id)
ORDER BY
  n.id DESC
```

How can I change it to get the last ?

Comment: Explain *doesn't work*. You get any error or produce wrong result?

Comment: what is your aspected output?

Comment: @MahediSabuj I have edited my question

Comment: @denny I have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**you should use left outer join like this :**

```
SELECT
n.id,
n.object_url,
n.object_id,
n.activitytype_id,
cm.content AS activitycontent
FROM
  notifications n
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `COMMENT` AS cm ON cm.id = n.object_id and n.activitytypeId  = 1
WHERE
  n.recipient_id = 1
GROUP BY
   n.activitytype_id,
   n.object_url
 HAVING MAX(cm.id)
ORDER BY
  n.id DESC
```

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer without noticed that your query gives me the first comment. How can I change it to get the last ?

Comment: I have edited your answer and It works now. Thank you